# Console No Response Problem

Tags: developer-console

When i try to access object from developer console i get an error like below picture.

[image]

Also, when i use query editor and update some value on console, i get an error like below picture.

[image]

One more, when i try to update this object records from anonymous window, the log seems successful but the record isn't updated.

I don't get these errors except this object. I think there is something wrong with this object but i couldn't find what it is.

Help me!

Comment: Generally this error indicates there is internet connectivity issue. You can reset your network or probably restart your browser. This might solve the issue.

Comment: I have been getting this error for 1 month

Comment: You can check chrome developer console.  Press F12 and then look for the requests under the Network tab when you try to access the object. In particular, check the Response Headers.

Comment: can you check my another answer post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT indicates that the requests to load the resources required by the developer console is being blocked by the browser.

Most likely you have a Chrome extension such as Ad Block that is mistakenly blocking these requests.

How you fix this will depend on the extension involved. It could be as simple as adjusting the settings in the extension. Or you could disable all the browser extensions to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Yeah found it. Thank you! that you mentioned, it happens because of extension